# Snow Leopard sqlite3-ruby installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, osx-snow-leopard

I'm running Mac OSX Snow Leopard, this problem is caused by a recent [train wreck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422192/train-wreck-rails-requires-rubygems-1-3-2) in which I updated ruby without RVM. I've attempted to properly install/run RVM, however I can't get it to work.

I am unable to install the sqlite3-ruby gem. I get the following **ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

How do I fix this?

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
$ whereis rails
/usr/bin/rails
$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
$ whereis gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.11)
columnize (0.3.1)
erubis (2.6.5)
fastercsv (1.5.1)
ffi (0.6.3)
gbarcode (0.98.16)
i18n (0.3.5)
linecache (0.43)
mail (2.1.3)
memcache-client (1.8.0)
prawn (0.8.4)
prawn-core (0.8.4)
prawn-layout (0.8.4)
prawn-security (0.8.4)
rack (1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.1)
rack-test (0.5.3)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)
rubygems-update (1.3.6)
sqlite3 (0.0.8)
text-format (1.0.0)
thor (0.13.4)
tzinfo (0.3.17)

$ sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for fdatasync() in -lrt... no
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_open() in -lsqlite3... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --with-rtlib
    --without-rtlib
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out
```

**profile:**

```
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH    
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
if [[ -s /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373108/snow-leopard-sqlite3-ruby

Comment: He is still on 1.8, that link probably won't make a difference. I am sure it's to do with the Developer tools not being installed yet.

Comment: justin-zollarss-mac-pro:~ justinz$ sudo ln -s  /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
Password:
ln: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib: File exists

Comment: In order to correct this problem I uninstalled sqlite3 gem, and installed sqlite3-ruby gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall the sqlite3 gem and then try again -- i seem to recall that sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby aren't compatible.  otherwise, append the results file to your question so we can see what went wrong when the compilation happened.

Comment: JZ, have you had a chance to check this out?

Comment: In order to correct this problem I uninstalled sqlite3 gem, and installed sqlite3-ruby gem

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode. You can download it at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) for free.

Comment: reinstalled xcode, that wasn't the problem :( would have been an easy fix

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same error without having the sqlite3 gem installed. Uninstalled sqlite3 with macports (and dependencies as well). After the uninstall, sqlite3-ruby install worked fine.